# What kind of indexing to use for a varchar field where I only need to check if something exist?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Here is my current table;

```
CREATE TABLE `linkler` (
  `link` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `link` (`link`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I will only use these 2 queries on the table, `SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM linkler WHERE link = ?)` and `INSERT INTO linkler (link) VALUES (?)`

I don't know much about indexing databases. Since I won't be adding same thing twice, I thought marking it unique would be a good idea. Is there anything I can do to increase performance? For example, can I do something that rows are always sorted so that mysql can do binary search or something similiar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a unique index is perfect.  Also, since you have a unique index, you don't need to check for existence before you do an insert.  You can simply use `INSERT IGNORE` to insert the row if it doesn't exist (or ignore the error if it does):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO linkler (link) VALUES (?)
```

Whether that will be faster than doing a SELECT/INSERT combination depends on how often you expect to have duplicates.

ETA: If that is the only column in this table, you might want to make it a `PRIMARY KEY` instead of just a `UNIQUE KEY` although I don't think it really matters much other than for clarity.